# EF 4 - Append to a Field on UPDATE

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am trying to append to a field but when I try the following, the existing data (Update.Comments) gets overwritten with followUpComments instead of appending to it.

How do I append?

```
    using (var context = new DBContext()){

        var Update = (from p in context.Prospects where p.id == recordIdToUpdate select p).Single();

        Update.Comments = Update.Comments + "\n\n" +followUpComments;

        context.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using String.Concat instead of +

Comment: James, using String.Concat() fixed it. Not sure why the "+" operator did not work. Post that as a solution and I will give you credit and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use String.Concat instead of + operator